# Biginteger Addition in C++

Tags: c++, string-length

I am trying to add two big integers. Here is a function I have made. `s1` is the larger string in it. During passing the function parameter I will account for the string length. The code works fine for all values except those having 10^(n). As such it shows o/p as 2 for 100 + 2. Similarly for other power of 10 cases. When I did some digging I noticed that the for loop runs just once for these cases. As such `s1.length()` reports length as 1. How can I fix it ?

```
void addBigInteger (string s1,string s2) {
    string str3;
    reverse(s1.begin(),s1.end());
    reverse(s2.begin(),s2.end());
    int temp = 0,carry=0,i;
    for (i=0;i<s1.length();i++) {

        if ((i+1) > s2.length())
            s2[i] = '0';

        temp = s1[i]-'0'+s2[i]-'0'+carry;
        str3[i] = temp%10 + '0';
        carry = temp/10;
    }
    while (carry!=0) {
        str3[i++] = carry%10 + '0';
        carry = carry/10;
    }

    for (i;i>=0;i--) {
        cout << str3[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `if ((i+1) > s2.length()) s2[i] = '0';` obviously writes out of bound.

Comment: As do all the writes to `str3`.

Comment: @timrau That is the thought here. If say length of s2 is 2 and that of s1 is 5, then all other digits of s2 will be made to '0' for addition. However now that you've said it, I'm gonna see if I can still add within bounds. Thanks for pointing out.   EDIT : It doesn't work by simply commenting that part out. Guess I'll have to do something with bound checking

Comment: Use a bignum library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/) or something else.

Comment: @g33kyaditya Weird why you reverse everything to start, and fail to "unreverse" your answer at the end.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The answer was printed in reversed order of string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I got away with it by displaying the output from the last.

Comment: @timrau I know the answer is printed in reverse order, but for utility purposes, I would expect that if I add two bigints, I get a bigint in the proper order returned, not a reversed answer.  80 + 80 = 160, not 061.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `str2.push_back('0')` to append characters instead of assigning `str2[i]` with out-of-bound `i`. `std::string::operator[]` does not "grow" the internal storage in the string.

Comment: Still the same output for inputs like : s1 = 100 s2 = 2 str3 = 2

Comment: @g33kyaditya [This](http://ideone.com/H6mGnT) just works fine without valgrind error. How does your latest code looks like?

Comment: Okay. I got it. One last question , When do I use push_back in place of [...] ? Since from what I understand they are the same with the exception of push_back appending to the end.

Comment: @g33kyaditya Just remember: never use `operator[]` to make a string longer.

Comment: You cannot use `operator [ ]` if the index is out of bounds.  No different than arrays.